# Combine results after join and groupby with DataTable and List<Object>

Tags: c#, .net, linq, datatable

I'd like to combine the results of a LINQ join between a DataTable and a List.

This works just fine:

```
var lpYear = (
    from a in _ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
    join b in LandingPages on a["OFFERINGKEY"].ToString() equals b.Code into c
    from d in c.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where DateTime.Parse(a["PURCHASEDATE"].ToString()) >= DateTime.Parse("January 1, " + year)
    where DateTime.Parse(a["PURCHASEDATE"].ToString()) >= DateTime.Parse("December 31, " + year)
    where LandingPages.Any(x => x.Code == a["OFFERINGKEY"].ToString())
    orderby d.Title
    select new {
        title = d.Title,
        price = a["PRICE"]
    }).GroupBy(o => o.title)
    .Select(o => new { 
        total = o.Sum(p => decimal.Parse(p.price.ToString())), 
        count = o.Count(),
        title = o.Key
    }
);
```

And I end up with rows containing "`total | count | title`".

What I'd like to do is add some more columns.  For example, `LandingPage.URL` or `LandingPage.Code`.  I've tried like this, but it doesn't work:

```
var lpYear = (
    from a in _ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
    join b in LandingPages on a["OFFERINGKEY"].ToString() equals b.Code into c
    from d in c.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where DateTime.Parse(a["PURCHASEDATE"].ToString()) >= DateTime.Parse("January 1, " + year)
    where DateTime.Parse(a["PURCHASEDATE"].ToString()) >= DateTime.Parse("December 31, " + year)
    where LandingPages.Any(x => x.Code == a["OFFERINGKEY"].ToString())
    orderby d.Title
    select new {
        title = d.Title,
        price = a["PRICE"],
        url = d.URL,
        code = d.Code
    }).GroupBy(o => o.title)
    .Select(o => new { 
        total = o.Sum(p => decimal.Parse(p.price.ToString())), 
        count = o.Count(),
        title = o.Key,
        url = o.Select(p=>p.url),
        code = o.Select(p=>p.code)
    }
);
```

This is the resulting value for `url` and `purchased`:

```
System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[<>f__AnonymousType2`3[System.String,System.Object,System.String],System.String]
```

**The Solution** *(thanks to [Cédric Bignon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1284526/cedric-bignon))*:

Place `.First()` at the end of my `o.Select(p=>p.url)` lines:

```
url = o.Select(p=>p.url).First(),
code = o.Select(p=>p.code).First()
```

Comment: Why don't you use LINQ syntax (instead of extention methods) from begin to end of your query? It may simplify making reference between multiple parts of the query. When you say "it doesn't work, what is the problem exactly?"

Comment: I have tried with various extension method configurations (I think) and using the `.GroupBy()` and `.Select()` seemed to the only way to do what I needed.  Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just forgot the `ToList()`, to enumerate the ... enumerations when you do `o.Select(...)`

```
var lpYear = (
    from a in _ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
    join b in LandingPages on a["OFFERINGKEY"].ToString() equals b.Code into c
    from d in c.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where DateTime.Parse(a["PURCHASEDATE"].ToString()) >= DateTime.Parse("January 1, " + year)
    where DateTime.Parse(a["PURCHASEDATE"].ToString()) >= DateTime.Parse("December 31, " + year)
    where LandingPages.Any(x => x.Code == a["OFFERINGKEY"].ToString())
    orderby d.Title
    select new {
        title = d.Title,
        url = d.URL,
        price = a["PRICE"],
        purchased = a["PURCHASEDATE"].ToString()
    }).GroupBy(o => o.title)
    .Select(g => new { 
        total = g.Sum(p => decimal.Parse(p.price.ToString())), 
        count = g.Count(),
        title = g.Key,
        url = g.Select(p=>p.url).Distinct().Single(),
        code = g.Select(p=>p.code).Distinct().Single()
    }
);
```

In pure LINQ:

```
var lpYear = from o in (from a in _ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                        join b in LandingPages on a["OFFERINGKEY"].ToString() equals b.Code into c
                        from d in c.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        where DateTime.Parse(a["PURCHASEDATE"].ToString()) >= DateTime.Parse("January 1, " + year)
                        where DateTime.Parse(a["PURCHASEDATE"].ToString()) >= DateTime.Parse("December 31, " + year)
                        where LandingPages.Any(x => x.Code == a["OFFERINGKEY"].ToString())
                        orderby d.Title
                        select new 
                        {
                            title = d.Title,
                            url = d.URL,
                            price = a["PRICE"],
                            purchased = a["PURCHASEDATE"].ToString()
                        })
             group o by o.title into g
             select new 
             { 
                 total = g.Sum(p => decimal.Parse(p.price.ToString())), 
                 count = g.Count(),
                 title = g.Key,
                 url = (from p in g
                        select p.url).Distinct().Single(),
                 code = (from p in g
                         select p.code).Distinct().Single()
             };
```

Comment: After adding `.ToList()`, it returns the following for 'url' and 'purchased': `System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]`

Comment: Yes, it is normal behavior because you are doing a grouping. _g_ can contain multiple elements that have different _price_ or _purchased_ values. If you are sure these values are the same for all the elements of the group _g_, use _Single_ instead of _ToList_.

Comment: Okay, got it. `.Single()` produced an error, but `.First()` worked like a charm.  Your "pure LINQ" example also works and does the same thing (it's missing a closing ')' on line 14).  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Be careful _First_ because it only takes the first element of the enumeration. In fact, I was wrong when I said to replace _ToList()_ by _Single()_ (it only works if each group is composed with only 1 element). It would be more correct to replace it by _Distinct().Single()_. Indeed, in this case, if all the prices in a group are all the purchased value are not equal, it raises an error (error you won't see using only _First()_).
And thanks for the missing ')'.

Comment: Thanks for explaining - that makes sense.  Also, `purchased` and `price` are terrible examples.  The real data I'll be pulling in is `url` and `code` etc. - I've updated my original post to reflect this.